# When deriving the equation of a plane from a normal vector u, how can all dimensions vary?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have searched for clarity on my questions(s) pretty extensively, yet I'm still not getting it. I see the same questions in other posts on this site, but they all seem to reiterate the plane formula from a plane point and normal vector.

What I don't understand is: In three dimensions, if we have the equation of a plane from a point and unit vector, how can all of the dimensions vary?

I'm picturing a plane that the origin (0,0,0) goes through. Every z coordinate = 0. Point (2, 2, 0) is also on this plane. A normal vector to this plane would be u = [1, 1, 2]. This gives a plane formula of a + b + 2c = 4.

Doesn't the c dimension have to remain constant? I hope the way I'm seeing this is clear; however incorrect.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, but note that if the z coordinate of all points in the plane is zero, then you're dealing with the $xy$ plane and $(1,1,2)$ is definitely not a normal vector.

Comment: As for the claim "all of the dimensions vary," note that a plane in three dimensions has only two degrees of freedom. Once you specify two Cartesian coordinates, the third coordinate is determined by an equation of the form $ax+by+cz=d$.

Comment: Where do you get the sentence "A normal vector to this plane would be $u=(1,1,2)$?"

Comment: How do you mean, Ted? Isn't it?

Comment: @symplectomorphic That's how I'm seeing the xy plane... with a vector u = [1, 1, 2] being perfectly 'vertical', therefore perpendicular to x,y plane. So that isn't the case? Still wondering what I'm missing...

Comment: Of course the vector $(1,1,2)$ is not perpendicular to the $xy$ plane. The only such vectors have the form $(0,0,c)$: those are the vectors that point up or down. For example, the vector $(1,0,0)$ is in the $xy$ plane but the dot product of this vector with your alleged normal vector is $1$, not $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments have mentioned your normal vector is off. The normal vector to the $xy$ plane, by convention is $\hat{k}=<0,0,1>$. But nonetheless we can show this other ways. Given your information we have the points
$$(0,0),(2,2,0), \, \text{and}\,(a,b,0)$$
All of which lie on the plane. The last one is obtained by the fact that you mentioned all $z$ coordinates are zero. This gives us two vectors that lie in the plane:
$$\vec{v}_1=<2,2,0>\,\text{and}\,\,\vec{v}_2=<a,b,0>$$
We can then get a normal vector to the plane by taking their cross product
$$\vec{N}=\vec{v}_1\times \vec{v}_2=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
2 & 2 & 0 \\
a & b & 0 \\
\end{array}\right|=\hat{i}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\
b & 0 \\
\end{array}\right|-\hat{j}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\
a & 0 \\
\end{array}\right|+\hat{k}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 2 \\
a & b \\
\end{array}\right|$$
$$=\hat{i}\cdot 0-\hat{j}\cdot 0+2\hat{k}(b-a)$$
Thus normal vectors to such a plane are of the form
$$\vec{N}=<0,0,2(b-a)>=<0,0,c>\quad c\in\mathbb{R}$$
Hence the reason your equation is off is because of the normal vector.